# How to convert int 1 into ascii 1 in python?

Tags: python, integer, ascii, encode

I receive input that is in a float format. I've broken it up into individual int numbers and am trying to encode them as the same ascii characters. Ie: int 1 to ascii character 1.

I have tried different variations of this:

```
x = 1
y = chr(x)
print (y)
```

which results in ascii character SOH instead of ascii character 1.

Comment: How about `y = str(x)`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The ultimate goal is to convert the initial int into the hex version of the ascii character. Attempting to hex a string results in an ''str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer' error.

Comment: `y = f'{ord(str(1)):x}'` *(note: the `x` is not the variable, it stands for hexadecimal output)*

Comment: That "ultimate goal" should have been part of the question itself, as that's the original problem you want to solve. Without that information your question is really an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @KlausD. That outputs as what I am looking for but without the 0x prefix. Do you happen to know if it is there and just not visible when printing? Thanks.

Comment: You could try to do a little part of the job on your own, like adding the `0x` to the f-string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functions chr(),ord() and str() to encode it like that, I think what you want is the result of this.

```
x=1
print(chr(ord(str(x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading, This is what I was looking for:

```
y = f'0x{ord(str(1)):x}'
```

which outputs:

0x31